# How to reverse ordering for RDD.takeOrdered()?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

What is the syntax to reverse the ordering for the takeOrdered() method of an RDD in Spark?

For bonus points, what is the syntax for custom-ordering for an RDD in Spark?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Reverse Order**

```
val seq = Seq(3,9,2,3,5,4)
val rdd = sc.parallelize(seq,2)
rdd.takeOrdered(2)(Ordering[Int].reverse)
```

*Result will be Array(9,5)*

**Custom Order**

We will sort people by age.

```
case class Person(name:String, age:Int)
val people = Array(Person("bob", 30), Person("ann", 32), Person("carl", 19))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(people,2)
rdd.takeOrdered(1)(Ordering[Int].reverse.on(x=>x.age))
```

*Result will be Array(Person(ann,32))*

Comment: To do Ascending Sort we need to do >>>rdd.takeOrdered(2) or >>>rdd.takeOrdered(2)(Ordering[Int]) . As by default it is sorted in Ascending Order. But instead a more optimized way of doing it by using top(2) command.

Comment: For Ordering Custom In Ascending >>>rdd.takeOrdered(1)(Ordering[Int].on(x=>x.age)).foreach(println)... For Ordering Custom on String Field of an Object >>>rdd.takeOrdered(1)(Ordering[String].on(x=>x.name)).foreach(println)

Answer (score 8):

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List(("Hadoop PIG Hive"), ("Hive PIG PIG Hadoop"), ("Hadoop Hadoop Hadoop")))

val rdd2 = rdd1.flatMap(x => x.split(" ")).map(x => (x,1))

val rdd3 = rdd2.reduceByKey((x,y) => (x+y))
```

**//Reverse Order (Descending Order)**

```
rdd3.takeOrdered(3)(Ordering[Int].reverse.on(x=>x._2))
```

**Output:**

```
res0: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Hadoop,5), (PIG,3), (Hive,2))
```

**//Ascending Order**

```
rdd3.takeOrdered(3)(Ordering[Int].on(x=>x._2))
```

***Output:***

```
res1: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((Hive,2), (PIG,3), (Hadoop,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

for a wordcount type of problem with K,V pair. If you want to get last 10 from your ordered list -

```
SparkContext().parallelize(wordCounts.takeOrdered(10, lambda pair: -pair[1]))
```